# How can I make a feature in the JavaFX client which enables the user to choose which web server he wants to connect to?

Tags: web-services, wcf-client

I have a  JavaFX webservice client mobile application.

How can I make the JavaFX client wherein the user can choose which IP address of the WCF servers(I have more than 1 web servers) he wants to connect to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the endpoint address